# Product of probabilities conditioning on different events

Tags: probability, independence

Let $A,B,C,D$ be some events. Consider the probabilities
$$
Pr(A|C)
$$
and
$$
Pr(B|D)
$$
Under which conditions it holds that
$$
Pr(A|C)\times Pr(B|D)=Pr(A,B|C,D)
$$
?

Comment: The following condition is sufficient: A and B are independent and C and D are independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We, given the definition of conditional probability, we have that 
$$P(A|C)P(B|D) = \frac{P(A,C)}{P(C)}\cdot \frac{P(B,D)}{P(D)} = \frac{P(A,C)P(B,D)}{P(C)P(D)}.$$

Now similarly, $$P(A,B|C,D) = \frac{P(A,B,C,D)}{P(C,D)}.$$

Now, if $C$ and $D$ are independent, we have that $P(C,D) = P(C)P(D).$ Similarly, if $(A,C)$ is indendent of $(B,D)$, then $P(A,B,C,D)=P(A,C)P(B,D).$ Letting $\perp$ denote independence, we then have a sufficient (but not necessary) condition is $C \perp D, C \perp B, A \perp B, A\perp D.$

Comment: Thanks. Would $(A\perp B|C,D)$, $(A\perp D|C)$, $(B\perp C|D)$ work as well?

Comment: I was assuming that $A,B,C,D$ are each sets. As such, I'm not sure what $A|C$ means. I don't know how you can define that set. The notation, $P(A|C)$ is not the probability of a set $A|C$ but rather the probability of $A,C$ scaled by the probability of $C$.

Comment: I see the point. Thanks

Comment: @David The expression $~A\perp D\mid C~$ reads as: "$A,D$ are conditionally independent given $C$".  IE $\def\P{\mathop{\sf P}} ~\P(A,D\mid C)=\P(A\mid C)\P(D\mid C)~$ ... thus also $~\P(A\mid C,D)=\P(A\mid C)~$ (when $\P(D\mid C)\neq 0$). $$\begin{align}\P(A,B\mid C,D)~&=~\P(A\mid C,D)\P(B\mid C,D) &~\because~& {A\perp B\mid C,D}\\ & =~ \P(A\mid C)\P(B\mid C,D) &~\because~& {A\perp D\mid C}\\ &=~ \P(A\mid C)\P(B\mid D) &~\because~& B\perp C\mid D\end{align}$$ So, yes, those three conditions would suffice.

Comment: @grahamkemp ah yes, that makes sense. I hadn't seen that he edited his comment after my responce.